# How to focus on an object in a diagram in Enterprise Architect?

Tags: enterprise-architect

Developing an Extension in Enterprise Architect, it's possible to call **Repository.OpenDiagram()** function and open a specific diagram. Using the **Diagram.SelectedObjects**, objects on that diagram can be selected and the list of the selected ones is accessible. However, there I need to focus on a selected object, but cannot find the corresponding EA API/function.

**How** could I **focus on an object** so that it be displayed in the **center of diagram** window (without changing the real position of the object)?

Thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 1):

You can't, except if you use a windows library to simulate clicks on the scrollbar or something like that.

But I'm not recommending that approach as you'll never be sure it will actually put the element in the center.

Comment: What about simulating **Ctrl + U** event? 
Calling **Repository.ShowInProjectView()** selects the element in the project tree view and then triggering "Ctrl + U" must locate it in the diagram. However I don't have any idea to issue such event by my program.

Comment: That's an idea. There's loads of results when you google for "How to simulate key press" or similar.

Comment: I just tried the following code and partially resolved the problem: `repository.ShowInProjectView(Element);
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send("^u");` 
However, it has some problems. It requires the "Project Browser" window be foreground, and anyway it's not a clean solution!